# How can the s3 JsonFormat format.class be configured to not output fields with null values?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I can't change the model or change annotations. This has to be done from the kafka connect side. I want the output of the io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat to not output fields that have null values.

`"field1":null,"field2":"","field3:"value"`

I only want field3 to be output; null and empty string fields should be ignored.

I can make a new format.class that implements the interface. Before I go down that path, I wanted to see if there was a a way to do it with the configuration of the transforms, the format class or otherwise.

Comment: Last I checked, null values in Kafka records aren't written at all, but maybe that's the Avro format

Comment: Let me edit my question, I meant null fields.

Comment: Got it. In that case, there's no such builtin feature that I'm aware of since it would require parsing the entire message and iterating over every record and nested object